# Generate your own compilation error\warning with macro-like function

Tags: c, gcc

I want to generate a compilation error or warning depending on, for example, what is written in a string, in the following main i wanted that if the string is uninitialized that will generate a compilation error (Obviusly that does not work i want tho know the right way to do it).

```
#define EXAMPLE_FUNCTION(s1) ({ \
    int n = 0;\
    if (s1) {n = 1;} \
    n; \
    })
int    main()
{
    char *str = NULL;
    #if (EXAMPLE_FUNCTION(str) == 0)
    #error whatever error
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

This one is a redundant example, but i want to do what printf does when he founds a wrong  format, for example if i write this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%0s\n", "whatever string");
    return 0;
}
```

Gcc returns the following warning:

```
prueba2.c:5:11: warning: flag '0' results in undefined behavior with 's' conversion specifier [-Wformat]
        printf("%0s\n", "whatever string");
                ~^~
1 warning generated.
```

The matter is how to generate those kind of errors in compilation time.

Comment: Are you looking for `static_assert`?

Comment: yes, i think so, thanks :)